# How to fix an issue I have with pandas.json in Python?

Tags: python, json, pandas, future-warning

I am trying to run a code in Python.

I upload the libraries as follow:

```py
import requests
import json
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import re
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
```

And when I try to extract information from a web site I receive the following error:

```
C:\Users\Mike\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:1: FutureWarning: pandas.io.json.json_normalize is deprecated, use pandas.json_normalize instead
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is the warning not clear? just use `pd.json_normalize` as the `from pandas.io.json` variant seems it will be depreciated in future.

Comment: No, the warning is not clear. The suggestion does not solve my issue.

Answer (score 7):

Pandas now contains the json_normalize functions as pandas.io.json is deprecated.

Replace this:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
```

With this:

```
from pandas import json_normalize
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete `from pandas.io.json import json_normalize` from your imports, and replace `json_normalize` with `pd.json_normalize` in your code.

Comment: Then you need to provide your code or improve the question description. The error you have presented is literally telling you to do this.

Comment: When I do the next step:

```import requests
import json
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import re
pd.json_normalize```

I receive the next answer:

<function pandas.io.json._normalize._json_normalize(data: Union[Dict, List[Dict]], record_path: Union[str, List, NoneType] = None, meta: Union[str, List[Union[str, List[str]]], NoneType] = None, meta_prefix: Union[str, NoneType] = None, record_prefix: Union[str, NoneType] = None, errors: Union[str, NoneType] = 'raise', sep: str = '.', max_level: Union[int, NoneType] = None) -> 'DataFrame'>

Comment: If I do:

```import requests
import json
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import re
import pandas from pd.json_normalize```

I get: Invalid syntax